# Angle between vectors and using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Tags: linear-algebra

> Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the inner product generated by the matrix
>   $A =
> \begin{bmatrix}2&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$.
>
> (a) Find the angle between the vectors $\vec{u} = (3, 3)$ and $\vec{v} = (5, −8)$.
>
> (b) Show that $(\vec{v}^TA^TA\vec{u})^2 \leq (\vec{v}^TA^TA \vec{u})(\vec{v}^TA^TA\vec{v})$ either by direct calculation or by using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

For part (a), how would I find the angle between the vector $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$? I'm not sure how to incorporate the inner product in matrix $A$.

For part (b), how would I use the inequality theorem to prove that statement?

Comment: The inner product generated by $A$ is $\langle\mathbf u,\mathbf v\rangle = \mathbf v^TA\mathbf u$.

Answer (score 0):

CS inequality is $<u,v>\leq \vert u\vert . \vert v \vert $, or ${<u,v>\over \vert u\vert . \vert v \vert}\leq 1$. Indeed, ${<u,v>\over \vert u\vert . \vert v \vert}$ is the cosinus of the angle of the pair of vectors $u,v$. Apply this to $Au, Av$, you find the cos of the angle (this solve a), and as this cosinus is $\leq 1$ you have proven the CS inequality, or b.